# Yii2 Kartik DatePicker - CSS

Tags: css, datepicker, yii2

I am starting to use the Yii2 Kartik helpers.

The issue i am having is the CSS of the datepicker

[image: CSS Error]

As you can see the Date of Birth field has no padding at the bottom.

The code for the fields around it

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'mobile')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'telephone')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'date_of_birth') ?>
<?= DatePicker::widget([
    'model' => $model, 
    'attribute' => 'date_of_birth',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter birth date ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    ]
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'user_id')->textInput() ?>
```

From the CSS i can see that the Kartik creates a div with the class input-group

```
<div id="staff-date_of_birth-kvdate" class="input-group date">
```

Where as the standard form element have a div with the class form-group

```
<div class="form-group field-staff-telephone">
```

Any ideas?

Regards

Liam

Answer (score 2):

You should simply try :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date_of_birth')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter birth date ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    ],
]) ?>
```

Read more : http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker#usage